# Microsoft Visual Studio- Project error

Tags: c++, build, build-error

I am adding some new functionality to an existing program that has been written in C++. Having made several changes to the code, and been able to build it successfully numerous times, after making the latest change, I tried building the code again, but this time the build has failed.

Usually when it fails it's due to some error in the code that I've written. However, this time, the reason given for the fail is a `Project error`, which is something I've not come across before... The full error message is:

```
1>Project : error PRJ0002 : Error result 31 returned from 'C:\Program Files\
```

and it appeared in the console just after

```
1>Linking...
1>Embedding manifest...
```

It doesn't indicate that it's anything to do with any specific part of the code... Does anyone have any idea what this error means? What do I need to do to resolve it?

Comment: Error 31 is ERROR_GEN_FAILURE, "A device attached to the system is not functioning."  Perhaps you ought to panic, but disable anti-malware first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most usually it happens because of AV software. Try ignoring VC++ directories in your antivirus software. And you can also clean project and retry, it's a temporary issue.

Comment: Yeah, I had given cleaning the project a go, but that didn't resolve it the first time. Thankfully, it did the second time.